# DrawView save combined image (multiply)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have 2 UIImageViews - one is at the bottom and shows a default image (like an Photo) - on the second UIImageView where you can draw.

I would like to create an UIImage from both images, and save it as new image.

How can i do that? Ill tried with:

```
 func saveImage() {

    print("save combined image")

    let topImage = self.canvasView.image
    let bottomImage = self.backgroundImageView.image

    let size = CGSizeMake(topImage!.size.width, topImage!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)

    [topImage!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, topImage!.size.height))];
    [bottomImage!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, bottomImage!.size.height))];

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, self, #selector(CanvasViewController.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

}
```

But the result is not correct (stretched and no overlay)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ill found an solution for that, just need to add "multiply" as blend mode.

```
    let topImage = self.canvasView.image
    let bottomImage = self.backgroundImageView.image

    let size = CGSizeMake(bottomImage!.size.width, bottomImage!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)


    [bottomImage!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, bottomImage!.size.height))];

    [topImage!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, bottomImage!.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.Multiply , alpha: 1.0)];

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```